# How to suppress GCC warnings that take arguments?

Tags: c++, gcc, warnings, preprocessor

I'd like to suppress the warning `Wstringop-overflow` in a specific file, and I've tried to do so as follows

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wstringop-overflow"
...
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

But this fails to suppress the warning, which still shows up in the compilation output as `... warning: ... [-Wstringop-overflow=]`

The `=` indicates that the warning takes an argument, but there is also a version that doesn't (`[-Wstringop-overflow]`), and I'm guessing that what I'm doing is suppressing the latter, not the former.

I've also tried to suppress the warning by adding the option `-Wno-stringop-overflow`, but I'm not sure how to do that in just one file. The following fails, since `Wno-stringop-overflow` is not a legal identifier:

```
#define Wno-stringop-overflow
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I suppress all warnings of the form `[-Wstringop-overflow=]` in one specific file?

EDIT: I got the reasonable suggestion to provide a minimal reproducible example, so I'll do my best. This warning appears in a larger project, when building that project as a whole - it fails to appear when I compile the file in question separately. Neither was I able to create a minimal example to reproduce this particular warning. But I can provide the following example:

```
switch (true) {
default:
    break;
}
```

This produces the warning `-Wswitch-bool` (which takes no arguments). Compiling with `-Wall` is enough to make this warning appear.

I am able to suppress this warning via `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wswitch-bool"`, but then my question is: How do I activate `-Wno-switch-bool` in order to suppress this warning in only the file in question, via a preprocessor directive? Again,

```
#define Wno-switch-bool
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: Can you make a small program where you get this warning while using that pragma? Please also show what flags/options you use when compiling.

Comment: In other words, create a [mcve].

Comment: I haven't been able to do so, but I've provided a minimal reproducible example for a different warning. Some help there would shed light on my original question.